# Usage and meaning of "up" in "...worth at least a thousand pounds up in London"

Tags: meaning

> Two chairs like that must be worth at least a thousand pounds up in London.

I don't know what the 'up' mean in the sentence. I'm even not sure which words — perhaps either 'a thousand pounds' or 'in London' — are modified by it.

Comment: It is ambiguous.  On first reading I thought it was saying "a thousand pounds up" -- that is to say "over a thousand pounds".  But that interpretation clashes with the use of "at least" to modify the price.  It's poorly worded.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks: either "at least" or "up" is superfluous: "... worth at least a thousand pounds" or "worth a thousand pounds up(wards)".

Comment: @TrevorD - But my point was that, on second reading, you see that it's "up in London".  The old "garden path".

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I didn't even see that meaning - but I now agree it's ambiguous.

Comment: @TrevorD - Getting it right is probably actually harder for someone coming in and reading an extracted sentence than reading the stuff in a book, since your eyes aren't flowing with the text, and so they tend to "jump ahead" to the phrase without first absorbing the lead-in verbiage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Up" and "down" have meanings that refer to towns, cities, and other possible destinations.

Compare this meaning and example sentence for ["up" in the Oxford Learners' Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/up_1?q=up):

> (adverb) 1. towards or in a higher position
>
> They live up in the mountains.

The mountains are in a higher position. It'd be possible to just say "they live in the mountains," but the "up" gives an idea of relative position - they live *up* in the mountains compared to where the speaker is talking. (The valley? The plains? Anywhere else lower?)

What gets tricky is what precisely "higher position" is referring to. Is it elevation? Latitude? Political or economic prestige? For the last value (prestige) there is a specific meaning for "up":

> (adverb) 4. to or at an important place, especially a large city
>
> We're going up to New York for the day.

New York is down in elevation and latitude from Rochester, but someone from Rochester may well go "up to New York."

This adverb *up* commonly comes before prepositions like "up to," "up in," and "up at." "Down" has a contrasting meaning, and different locales or individuals may have their own idea of whether a city qualifies as "up" or "down" relative to them. (One can use both "down in London" and "up in London.")

Comment: Can "up" also mean northwards?

Comment: @stannius Couldn't say anything about formal use, but it certainly can in casual use. I've (in the US) seen "up in Canada" used pretty frequently.

Comment: @stannius Yes, and in the UK, which is where London is, that's exactly what it will mean.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I might be missing something in your comment, but you're aware that London is in the *south* east of England (and hence of the UK)?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Thank you, yes, I know where London is. There are plenty of places that are further south in the country than London; I was in one just a few days ago. But indeed the rest of us say we go _down_ to London! The point being that, in context, the term relates to north/southness, not altitude or prestige.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but we don’t know the context, so how can we know which interpretation is the correct one here? In that respect, this answer appears to cover all the bases.

Comment: @Steve My comment is based on an assumption, rightly or wrongly, that the context is "a British person using words" (the source material appears to be a story set in England, at the very least), and in such a context, "up to London" or "down to London" is generally based primarily on latitude. Without more data I'm loath to post an answer though, which is why I haven't! But I do find this answer's interpretation (which has mostly US-related references, and was written by an American) to be less likely.

Comment: @Steve FWIW, David's answer concludes the same thing in proper answery form

Answer (score 2):

I (born 1964) was brought up south of London so I have personal experience of this problem. We always went *up* to London. As there was no obvious altitude difference, I always assumed it meant "up north" but my dad (born 1916) assured me that London was always *up*. He was brought up north-west of London. He further told me that it was a rigid convention on the railways (and we would always have travelled by train) that the *up train* went to London and the *down train* came back.

[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Up-train) supports this claim that there are two different definitions in use, and this document from the the [Indian Railway Fan Club](https://www.irfca.org/faq/faq-number.html) (see section on "Up and Down Trains") says

> Down refers to a train travelling away from its headquarters (i.e., the homing railway) or from its Divisional headquarters, whichever is closer. Up refers to a train travelling towards its headquarters or divisional HQ, whichever is closer. [...]
>   History
>   In the UK, the convention was that all trains going to London were "up", and all those going away from it were "down".

I am pretty certain (from experience) that my dad *was* right, but equally certain that it is not common practice these days. It may well depend on direction - you might be more likely to go *up* to London if it were east than if it were south. I would definitely go *down* to London these days from where I am now in Scotland.

In short, I am sure *up* is definitely the direction of London, but we cannot be sure, without further context (i.e. date and location) if it meant "up north(ish)" or "towards the metropolis".

In this example, the implication is clearly that prices will be higher in London than where they are now.

Comment: I concur: without disputing your anecdote, in my experience (born 1987) that is not the "current" usage of the phrase (for some value of "current"). The average individual living in, say, York, will never claim to go "up" to London.

Comment: Yes, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, things like this do change. I have learnt Scots Gaelic and I was taught that you always go *up south* and *down north* but I have never actually heard this usage. Everyone I know just uses the English directions!

Comment: I too was brought up with the understanding that all trains (from whatever part of Britain) went **up** to London, presumably (and this is *my* interpretation) because London is the capital city.

Comment: @TrevorD I think the change in terminology reflects a cultural shift. When the railways were young, everyone in the Empire (whether in Edinburgh, Dublin or Bombay) was expected to bow down in the direction of London and Her Majesty Queen Victoria. We don't do that anymore.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I was talking about the 1950s - 1970s - not Victorian times! On reflection, I think it would be more accurate to say that the "up-line" always referred to the line towards London & the "down-line" to the opposite; I don't know about lines that were going neither towards nor away from London.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I belive that the use of 'up' to mean "towards the more significant plsce" is both older than the railways and applicable to other environments. For instance students went 'up' to Oxford or Cambridge and were sent 'down' for misdemeanors. Also there is a late victoran maritime disaster song called Three Score and Ten whose chorus says "_from Yarmouth **down** to Scarborough three hundred more were drowned_". As Scarborough is north of Yarmouth but Yarmouth is closer to London than Scarborough I think this is an example of that usage.